# Get more than 100 issues from redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I am trying to get issues from Redmine, but there is a limit of 100 issues. I tried to write a method in the model in order to get all the issues. Here's the whole class:

```
class IssueResource < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
  self.element_name = "issue"
  self.format = ActiveResource::Formats::XmlFormat

  def self.search params
    segment=IssueResource.find(:all,:params=>params)
    issues=segment
    while segment!= []
      segment=IssueResource.find(:all,:params=>params,:having => "id < "+segment.last.id.to_s)
      issues = issues+segment

    end
    return issues

  end
end
```

As you can see I am trying `having` and send multiple requests but it does not work.

PS: in the parameter there is always :limit => 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`having` is a SQL operator. Here you are not using `ActiveRecord`, but `ActiveResource` that performs an HTTP request. For security, a REST API will never allow you (or should never allow you) to provide SQL fragments to be arbitrary executed on the database.

If you read the [API documentation for Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) you will notice there is no `having` parameter. It's likely you invented it.

What you need to do in order to fetch all the issues, is to use the pagination `offset` and `limit`.

```
Paging example:
GET /issues.xml?offset=0&limit=100
GET /issues.xml?offset=100&limit=100
```